# Any way to use AirPush in Adobe AIR Mobile application

Tags: mobile, air, adobe

I working on creating mobile app for Android, and because of some useful features of Adobe AIR  such as easy to use video support, P2P etc., I have using it.

I need to integrate my app with mobile ads from Airpush (http://www.airpush.com), but documentation says: "Is there an Adobe AIR version of the Airpush SDK ?
Unfortunately no."

Is that true? Can I add Airpush SDK support via Native Extensions (ANE)? Any suggestions?